# Error : Access denied finding property "ro.serialno" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-11, imagedownload

I have written a  java code in Android Studio to download and display an image from the internet on a button click. It shows errors

> E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"

and

> Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!

The log:

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"**
W/wnloadingimages: type=1400 audit(0.0:36): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7213 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
V/StudioTransport: Agent command stream started.
V/StudioTransport: JNIEnv not attached
V/StudioProfiler: Memory control stream started.
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager
    Transformed class: android/app/IntentService
    Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/Instrumentation
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/location/LocationManager$ListenerTransport
    Transformed class: android/app/JobSchedulerImpl
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/job/JobServiceEngine$JobHandler
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/ActivityThread
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/Debug
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager
    Transformed class: android/app/job/JobService
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/PendingIntent
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/location/LocationManager
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: java/net/URL
**W/zygote: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
```

My entire code:

```
package com.example.downloadingimages;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView image1;
    public void downloadImage(View view) {
        Log.i("Info", "Button Tapped");
        imageDownloader task = new imageDownloader();
        Bitmap myImage;
        try {
            myImage = task.execute("https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.Djjwf_HTzjvMpkRpHdfpwwHaJ7?w=200&h=269&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.5&pid=1.7").get();
            image1.setImageBitmap(myImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public class imageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                return myBitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an error in your code. You can ignore it.